# libpng error: Not a PNG file

Tags: android, android-studio, imagem

Depois que editei o icone do meu aplicativo e rodei o emulador ele me aparece com o seguinte erro:

[image: erro]

Já procurei por imagens em outro formato, já revisei meu código e nada, alguém tem uma solução?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite,

A imagem está na pasta drawable?

Tenta colocar na pasta mipmap

Você pode ver mais detalhes [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28065267/mipmap-vs-drawable-folders).